# How to Change the row Background color based on cell value

Tags: c#, row, cell

I have tried with this code but it does not work for me .

```
for (int i = 0; i < GerezCmdsGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToDouble(GerezCmdsGridView.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value) == 0 || GerezCmdsGridView.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value == DBNull.Value)
    {
        GerezCmdsGridView.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }            
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by _does not work_ exactly? You get any exception or error message? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: yes it says , Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
and Which event should i use for this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the order of the conditions is problematic. You're first trying to convert the value to double. *Then* you check for `DBNull.Value`.

So you should switch the order:

```
if (GerezCmdsGridView.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value == DBNull.Value || 
    Convert.ToDouble(GerezCmdsGridView.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value) == 0)
```

If you're first trying to convert a dbnull (`Convert.ToDouble(DBNull.Value)`) an exception will be raised:

> System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition, if this column is `BoundField`, you can set it's [`NullDisplayText` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.nulldisplaytext) as well which value to show when you get `DBNull` value on that column.